# How to calculate the covariance matrix in (Xu and Knight 2010)?

Tags: covariance-matrix, gaussian-mixture-distribution, characteristic-function

## Setup

I'm reading (Xu and Knight 2010), which is a paper about estimating finite Gaussian mixture models using the CECF (Continuous Empirical Characteristic Function) method. The basic idea is to minimize a weighted distance between the empirical characteristic function (ECF) and the theoretical one (CF) with respect to parameters of the mixture distribution.

The weighted distance is given by this integral:

$$
D(\theta; \pmb{r}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
  |\mathrm{ECF}(t; \pmb{r}) - \mathrm{CF}(t, \theta)|^2 e^{-bt^2} dt
$$

Here, $\pmb{r}$ is the vector of *data* used to compute the empirical characteristic function.

The point of the paper is that this integral can be solved analytically, and the distance $D(\theta; \pmb{r})$ becomes a function that one can compute without integrals. I'll have to put a screenshot here since the function is pretty long:

[image]

This function involves the weighting parameter $b$ that influences the asymptotic covariance of the estimate. So I think the distance should really be written $D(\theta; \pmb{r}, b)$.

## Asymptotic covariance

By Proposition 2, the estimated mixture parameters $\hat\theta = \arg\min_{\theta} D(\theta; \pmb{r}, b)$ for a fixed $b$ are asymptotically normal with the following covariance matrix:

$$
\begin{cases}
\mathrm{Var}(\hat\theta) &= \Lambda^{-1}\Omega\Lambda^{-1}\\
\Lambda_{ij} &= \mathbb{E} \dfrac{
    \partial D^2(\theta; \pmb{r}, b)
}{
    \partial \theta_i \partial \theta_j
}\\
\Omega_{ij} &= \mathbb{E} \left(
\dfrac{\partial D(\theta; \pmb{r}, b)}{\partial \theta_i}
\dfrac{\partial D(\theta; \pmb{r}, b)}{\partial \theta_j}
\right)
\end{cases}
$$

## Question

*How does one compute these expectations?*

To me this looks similar to the Fisher information matrix which one estimates using the Hessian of the log-likelihood at the estimate $\hat\theta$. This makes sense because the log-likelihood is a sum, so when one differentiates it, they get a sum of derivatives (or Hessians), and this sum is basically the average ("empirical expectation").

But here $D(\theta; \pmb{r}, b)$ *isn't* just a sum over the data $\pmb r$. In fact, the *first* quantity is this *double* nested sum over the data, and the *last* quantity involves $K$ sums over the data. So, the result doesn't look like the *average* of anything to me.

Am I overthinking this, and is $\Lambda$ just the Hessian of $D$ evaluated at the estimates $\hat\theta$?

How do I compute $\Omega_{ij}$? I was thinking about computing the derivatives $\partial D(\theta; r_n, b) / \partial\theta_i$ *for each data point* $r_n \in \pmb r$, then calculating this sum:

$$
\Omega_{ij} \approx \frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N
\left[
\frac{
     \partial D(\theta;r_n,b)
}{\partial\theta_i}
\frac{
     \partial D(\theta;r_n,b)
}{\partial\theta_j}
\right]
$$

Is this the right approach?

Proof of Lemma 1 in the Appendix says:

> Recall that $\Omega_{ij} = \int \left(\frac{\partial D(\theta;r)}{\partial\theta_i} \frac{\partial D(\theta;r)}{\partial\theta_j}\right) \exp(-bt^2) dt$

...which seems weird because $D(\theta;r)$ *doesn't* depend on $t$, so one can move the product of derivatives out of the integral and compute $\left(\frac{\partial D(\theta;r)}{\partial\theta_i} \frac{\partial D(\theta;r)}{\partial\theta_j}\right) \int \exp(-bt^2) dt$, but this isn't an expectation, is it?

## References

- Xu, Dinghai, and John Knight. 2010. “Continuous Empirical Characteristic Function Estimation of Mixtures of Normal Parameters.” Econometric Reviews 30 (1): 25–50. https://doi.org/10.1080/07474938.2011.520565.